# Review Queue for Document error

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues, documentation-proposals

Quite a few times now I will go to the review queue and it will show there are a positive amount of changes needing review for **documentation**. **BUT** when I click then it will say the queue has been cleared, then it takes me back to the general review page where it shows that there are still the same number of changes needed??

I've been though the cycle quite a few times and am wondering is this is an error that needs attention or are there some reviews that I am possibly not allowed seeing or some other explanation.

**First View**

[image]

**Second View**

[image]

**Third View**

[image]

Please Note: This only happens with Documentation, Other reviews are getting updated and the number of reviews will update.